# What is a safe maximum temperature for an unused part of the house?

Tags: air-conditioning

We barely use our upstairs so I don't really care how hot it gets.  Except, I don't want to cause damage to the house. Considering Texas summers are easily in the 110s °F nowadays, how high can I safely set my thermostat without causing heat damage to my house?

Are there any heat sensitive house items I should look out for?

Comment: Note, the home Inspector mentioned something about walls cracking, especially around the triangular molding (don't know what the molding is really called) on the ceilings if the house gets and stays hot.  Has anyone heard of this?

Comment: Molding between the wall and ceiling is generally called crown molding. (Although the 'triangular' description is throwing me off here. Are you describing the way it forms the hypotenuse between the wall and ceiling?)

Comment: 110F is going to be outside the operating range of virtually all digital electronics, and these days all electronics are digital. If you have computers, cable/DSL modems, wireless routers, flat screen TVs, or the like, they could potentially be damaged by those temps. They will certainly suffer a shorter lifespan if exposed to it regularly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a house that I leave at 99 degrees for most of the summer.

Candles, chocolate, and candies all melted to some degree.

The house itself seems fine. I don't see any issues with wooden furniture splitting or sheetrock crumbling. The TV and DVDs still works as do battery powered items.

I am at 99 degrees because that is as high as my thermostat will go. I enter the house on occasion and I wanted it to be tolerable, otherwise I would have just turned the A/C off.

I'm in Phoenix so we don't have humidity or mold issues.

Comment: How long have you been doing this for?

Answer (score 0):

Any device sensitive to extremes of heat or cold should have temperature ranges printed on them. These are usually operating temperatures so you should be safe storing them outside that range.

The fabric of the building should withstand that heat (43° C) though you might find some paints starting to go soft, but I wouldn't expect this from interior paints. I've only seen gloss paint go soft, and only under direct sun light on a very hot day.